# Saying "Stop() called but track is not started or stopped" during merging a photo with a existing video by mediaMuxer

Tags: android, kotlin, video-processing

What is wrong in my code please help.....
here is the total code
at the end the execution its saying "**Stop() called but track is not started or stopped**"

**and the output path i am getting that is corrupted and not containing merged video.**

private fun mergeImageWithVideo(videoPath: String, imagePath: String) {

```
    val mediaMetadataRetriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()
    mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath)
    val videoFrameCount =
        mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_FRAME_COUNT)
            ?.toInt() ?: 0
    val videoFrameRate =
        mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_CAPTURE_FRAMERATE)
            ?.toFloat() ?: 30.0f

    // Load your overlay image
    val overlayBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath)
    val videoExtractor = MediaExtractor()
    videoExtractor.setDataSource(videoPath)


    // Prepare the output video
    showELog("gsfdjhagfhjua ext ${output.extension}")
    val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(output.absolutePath)
    val fileDescriptor = fileOutputStream.fd
    val mediaMuxer =MediaMuxer(fileDescriptor,MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4)
    val audioTrackIndex = getAudioTrackIndex(videoExtractor)
    val audioFormat = videoExtractor.getTrackFormat(audioTrackIndex)
    val videoTrackIndex3 = mediaMuxer.addTrack(audioFormat)

    val videoTrackIndex = getVideoTrackIndex(videoExtractor)
    val videoFormat = videoExtractor.getTrackFormat(videoTrackIndex)
    val videoTrackIndex2 = mediaMuxer.addTrack(videoFormat)
   
    mediaMuxer.start()

    lifecycleScope.launch() {
        val tim = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {


            // Iterate through video frames
            val frameInterval = (1000000.0 / videoFrameRate).toLong()

            for (i in 0 until videoFrameCount) {
                val frameTime = i * frameInterval
                val videoFrame = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(
                    frameTime,
                    MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC
                )
                val overlayedImage = overlayImageOnFrame(videoFrame!!, overlayBitmap)
                showELog("sdagagea  $overlayedImage")
                // Add the modified frame to the output video
                val buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(overlayedImage.byteCount)
                overlayedImage.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer)
                buffer.rewind()
                val bufferInfo = MediaCodec.BufferInfo()
                bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = frameTime
                bufferInfo.size = buffer.remaining()
                mediaMuxer.writeSampleData(videoTrackIndex2, buffer, bufferInfo)

            }


            // Release resources

        }
        mediaMuxer.stop()
        mediaMuxer.release()
        mediaMetadataRetriever.release()
        fileOutputStream.close()

        output.absolutePath

        showELog("agdafgerag ${output.absolutePath}")
        //shareFile=tim
        // findNavController().navigateSafe(R.id.action_checkUploadedVideoFragment_to_uploadedVideoFragment,null)
        //showELog("testing new merge code ${output.absolutePath}")
    }

}
```

private fun overlayImageOnFrame(videoFrame: Bitmap, overlayBitmap: Bitmap): Bitmap {
// Resize overlayBitmap if necessary to match the video frame size
if (videoFrame.width != overlayBitmap.width || videoFrame.height != overlayBitmap.height) {
val scaledOverlayBitmap =
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(overlayBitmap, videoFrame.width, videoFrame.height, false)
val resultBitmap =
Bitmap.createBitmap(videoFrame.width, videoFrame.height, videoFrame.config)
val canvas = Canvas(resultBitmap)
canvas.drawBitmap(videoFrame, 0f, 0f, null)
canvas.drawBitmap(scaledOverlayBitmap, 0f, 0f, null)
return resultBitmap
} else {
val resultBitmap =
Bitmap.createBitmap(videoFrame.width, videoFrame.height, videoFrame.config)
val canvas = Canvas(resultBitmap)
canvas.drawBitmap(videoFrame, 0f, 0f, null)
canvas.drawBitmap(overlayBitmap, 0f, 0f, null)
return resultBitmap
}
}

```
private fun getVideoTrackIndex(extractor: MediaExtractor): Int {
    for (i in 0 until extractor.trackCount) {
        val format = extractor.getTrackFormat(i)
        val mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME)
        if (mime?.startsWith("video/") == true) {
            return i
        }
    }
    throw RuntimeException("Video track not found")
}

private fun getAudioTrackIndex(extractor: MediaExtractor): Int {
    for (i in 0 until extractor.trackCount) {
        val format = extractor.getTrackFormat(i)
        val mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME)
        if (mime?.startsWith("audio/") == true) {
            return i
        }
    }
    throw RuntimeException("Audio track not found")
}
```

**I am trying to merge a image with a existing video .
I want to get a merge video with original audio.**

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues with your code:

1. You added an audio track to the `MediaMuxer`, but you are not writing any samples for it. This is probably the reason for the error.
2. You are reading video frames with `MediaMetadataRetriever` and `OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC`. This way you can get only I-frames (usually one frame per second or longer).
3. You are not encoding the video frames prior to writing them to the `MediaMuxer` although the declared video format probably implies some compression.

You can do both decoding and encoding using the [MediaCodec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec) API.